# Move linux command into shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want to create a shell script file that print out the used memory.

I made this command and run it successfully in command line

```
awk '/^-.*buffers.*cache.*/ {print $4/1000}' <(free -m)
```

But when transfer this script into sh file, I cannot run it.

```
# test.sh
#! /bin/bash
echo $(awk '/^-.*buffers.*cache.*/ {print $4/1000}' <(free -m))
```

Error

```
sh test.sh
# Error: command substitution: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Please explain this error and fix that shell script file. Thank you.

Comment: Use `bash test.sh`. Process substitution is a bash extension, it's not available in `sh`.

Comment: make your script executable and run it with `./myscript.sh` (don't explicitly call `sh`)

Comment: And get rid of the `# test.sh` line. The shebang has to be the first line.

Comment: Why are you using `echo`? Just run the `awk` command like you did in the command line.

Comment: @Aserre Your way is worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar I use that command inside a function, and call it in multiple places. That's why I use echo to get function output.

Comment: You don't need to use `echo` to get the function output. The function's output is the output of the commands inside it.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for that. I'm a newbie with shell. I will try it.